# C# : Selenium : How to find an element with respect to the innertext of another element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I just started to learn Selenium WebDriver and I collided with a few issues. 
I googled a lot, but it was unsuccessful.

So, I am going to write a parser of a website.

There is a kind of HTML.
[browser view and html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z5iX.png)

`<div class="view-wrapper">` is included
`<ul class="sport--list">` and its included a list of `<li class="sport--block">...</li>`

I am trying to check each class of sport-block's in a loop and found the section which includes key word like "Футбол"

[Футбол](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rgYR.png)

Then, when I found the proper section I am going to get value of non-static timer and then write it to file. It's my next step. I have to solve first of all my first trouble;

[timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94YJN.png)

The main issue is that there are a lot of divs of .
How can I found the proper one? I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                // Go to the home page
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.favorit.com.ua/ru/live/");
                // Get the page elements
                IList<IWebElement> ClassNamesElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("sport--block"));
                for (int i = 0; i < ClassNamesElements.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ClassNamesElements[i]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to set up the next condition for selection. Like "Where  includes something like Футбол".
And after that, I want to work only within the piece of HTML which corresponds to my proper sport--block

I am not able to use XPath of elements, cuz website is not static. And proper sport block can appear with random positon.

I don't need you write code instead of me. I just need some direction to continue my googling.

DId I choose the proper way to solve this task (C# + Selenium)? 
Please, give me a few clues or hints. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question. What have you tried already that didn't work? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is this post still being edited or is there a question somewhere in here?

Comment: Please provide some additional code, and what You've tried. Try to be more accurate about Your question.

UsuaLly You do like this:

List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourxpath"));

but provide some code You're tried and it failed, and some more information, html...

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't finish to describe my question at that time when I posted it. I done it.

Comment: Volunteers, OP have did update the question now with all the required information we have asked for. Kindly consider to retract the downvotes. @TheVee Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the *value of the non-static timer* with respect to several *keys* within the `<li class="sport--block">...</li>` tags, as there are multiple such `<li>` tags, you can write a function which will accept the *key value* as a `string` argument and print the relevant time.

- Function :

  ```
  public void print_key_timer(string myKey)
  {
      string myTime = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='sport--list']//li[@class='sport--block']/div[contains(@class,'sport--head')]//span[.='" + myKey + "']//following-sibling::ul[1]//ul[@class='events--list']//div[@class='event--head']//div[@class='time--block']/div[@class='event--timer']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
      Console.WriteLine(myTime);
  }
  ```
- Now you can call the function as many times you wish from anywhere within your program as :

  ```
  print_key_timer("Футбол")
  ```

Comment: I am trying now to write the proper way since the top of HTML. I added some code more. Please, check it.

Comment: @TheVee Don't change the question once you have received well researched Answers for your question. Accept the answer which solved your query and upvote the answers which helped you to solve your problem. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new Question. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out. For this question I am reverting back to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < ClassNamesElements.Count; i++){

   if(ClassNamesElements[i].GetText().Contains("Футбол")){ 
      Console.WriteLine(ClassNamesElements[i].GetText());
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot guys! I need some time to write some more code in my Visual Studio and try to use your answers. Can I ask more about this task here or should I create a new topic ?

Comment: Yep, I see this a loop, but

          Console.WriteLine(ClassNamesElements[i].GetText());
this line doesnt give me the way to get timer's value. I added some code to my question. Do you have ideas how is it possible to check each <li class="category--block sp_1"> and found a few timer's values. THank you in advance.